# Should I use “the” before “internet” in this case?

Tags: grammar

This question may sound a little silly, but I’m really confused if I should use “the” before the word “internet” in the following sentence:

> After having internet at home for the first time

OR

> After having **the** internet at home for the first time

Comment: Omit **the**. It's not like you have the entire internet at your house.

Comment: But I think "I have internet" sounds weird and non-fluent, because it is **the** Internet.  Probably the best thing is to avoid the issue entirely by rephrasing to something like "having internet access at home".

Comment: I've seen both used naturally in casual contexts.  I'm not sure if either is "wrong", per se.

Answer (score 1):

*The Internet* and *an internet* are different things.

Historically, computer networks that used IP (Internet Protocol) were internets (small I) and not necessarily connected to each other.

As internets became connected globally, you have *The Internet* (capital I, a proper noun) which defines a global network that happens to use IP as its underlying protocol.

So, what you have at home is a connection to the Internet.  You use the definite article.

I would suggest that going on to discuss whether a local internet is a subnet of the Internet, and similar points, is probably more technical that you require in this question.

Comment: While true, this seems to miss the intent of the original question. Perhaps edit to make a more clear ruling on the original question, whether it's appropriate to delete "the"?